# Ruby, How to prevent Redcarpet to render HTML code in the output?

Tags: ruby, markdown, redcarpet

I am using Redcarpet to render in a webpage data introduced by the User.

I see that it is very easy for the User to introduce malicious HTML code.

I am trying different Redcarpet initializer options to prevent any possible malicious code to be renderered in the output but nothing is working:

Trying `filter_html`:

```
markdown =
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(
    Redcarpet::Render::HTML,
    filter_html: true
  )

markdown.render("<style>style</style> <script>alert()</script>")

# => "<p><style>style</style> <script>alert()</script></p>\n"
```

Trying `scape_html`:

```
markdown =
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(
    Redcarpet::Render::HTML,
    escape_html: true
  )

markdown.render("<style>style</style> <script>alert()</script>")

# => "<p><style>style</style> <script>alert()</script></p>\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are options for the *renderer*, not the parser, so you need to pass them to the renderer, and then pass the configured renderer to the parser, e.g.:

```
markdown =
  Redcarpet::Markdown.new(
    Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(escape_html: true),
    # other parser options here, e.g.
    autolink: true
  )
```